# I need to erase the drawing drawn in a loop

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

Here is my code

```
while (true)
{
    gg = this.CreateGraphics();
    b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    p1 = new Pen(Color.Red);

    neuron.transferFunction_output();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (neuron.layer2[i] == 1)
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy2, (float)20, (float)20);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                gg.DrawLine(p1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy2, ox1 - 100 * (float)j, oy3);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b2, ox1 - 100 * i, oy2, (float)20, (float)20);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (neuron.layer3[i] == 1)
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy3, (float)20, (float)20);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                gg.DrawLine(p1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy3, ox1 - 100 * (float)j, oy4);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b2, ox1 - 100 * i, oy3, (float)20, (float)20);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (neuron.layer4[i] == 1)
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy4, (float)20, (float)20);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                gg.DrawLine(p1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy4, ox1 - 100 * (float)j, oy5);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b2, ox1 - 100 * i, oy4, (float)20, (float)20);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (neuron.layer5[i] == 1)
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b1, ox1 - 100 * i, oy5, (float)20, (float)20);
        }
        else
        {
            gg.FillEllipse(b2, ox1 - 100 * i, oy5, (float)20, (float)20);
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Application.DoEvents();
}//end while
```

Now i want to wipe the drawings made earlier in the loop.Means i dont need to show last drawing, drawn in the last iteration. If i use `Graphics.clear(Color.SomeColor)` then the whole background color changes after each iteration and that i dont want to do that. Secondly if declare a method that draws same lines but with white color(means a method working as an eraser) on the same track as earlier then my code gets too long and its memory taking and time taking because i have to use `Thread.Sleep()` in my code due to some reasons.
IS there any other way to erase the the last drawing?
Thanks in regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(true) {
    var g = someControl.CreateGraphics();
    draw(g);
}
```

That sort of construct will not work as well as one might hope.  This is why you need to call `DoEvents()` in your loop; you're blocking the message pump.  Also, you call `CreateGraphics()` and paint outside of the `OnPaint` handler, so anything you draw will be erased when the window performs a refresh.

You should move all of your drawing code into the `OnPaint` handler.  This will give you a new surface to draw to every time you need it (call `Invalidate()` to force a re-paint) and will get you in line with the Windows message pump, so you can remove that call to (nasty) `DoEvents()`.  You can still animate this way and your code becomes simpler.

You can update logical interactions within your loop and call `Invalidate()` when you're ready to paint the screen.

I would suggest some reading: [The Windows Message Loop.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: @HansPassant: A game loop does not require painting to be performed outside of the OnPaint handler (but you know this of course... I'm not sure if you meant that my response needs some work or the OP's code).

Comment: but when i write this.createGraphics() then to compiler this should be a initialization. Secondly kindly explain a little bit "OnPaint" handler. Frankly speaking i have heard this first time

Comment: @kashmirilegion: When Windows wants a window to be painted it will send a `WM_PAINT` message.  This in turn evokes the `OnPaint()` handler (and any override implementations).  When you call `CreateGraphics` you are causing contention with this model.  You are drawing over here, but the window is repainting over there.  You want those to be in sync, so your drawing logic should live in the `OnPaint` handler.